# Is it possible to find dependency between PostgreSQL functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL **9.2.10**

Suppose you have 2 PostgreSQL functions, 'called_function' and 'caller_function', second one is calling the first one. Exactly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION called_function () RETURNS varchar AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN 'something';
END;

CREATE FUNCTION caller_function () RETURNS varchar AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN called_function ();
END;
```

Now, using SQL and knowing only function name, I would like to find out if 'caller_function' calls some other function. Or if 'called_function' is called by some other function. Is it possible?

I tried to get function's OID (let's say it is '123') and then I looked into **pg_depend** table:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_depend dep WHERE dep.objid = 123 OR dep.objsubid = 123 OR dep.refobjid = 123 OR dep.refobjsubid = 123 OR dep.refobjsubid = 123;
```

But it finds only **pg_language** and **pg_namespace** dependency. Nothing more.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Moreover postgres supports different languages including C and it's not so easy to find dependencies in those. I can think of one workaround for plpgsql and sql functions: you could search through pg_proc table, for example: `select oid, proname from pg_proc where prosrc is not null and prosrc like '%<your function name>%'`. But that's not a very reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem to define a function and because of dependency It didn't work. Then I solved my problem with adding this command before the commands

```
SET check_function_bodies = false;
```

hope to help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Look at the table pg_proc for example :

```
select nspname,proname,prosrc from pg_proc join  pg_namespace nsp on (pronamespace=nsp.oid) where prosrc like '%called_function%'
```

Comment: ugh! I guess the answer is no, Postgress doesn't keep track of function dependencies, which is why you can create a function that depends on another that doesn't exist... because it blows up during runtime.  #sad

Answer (score 0):

Impossible in the general case; but a **limited** (restricted-domain) solution is perfectly doable --- and might prove adequate for your needs.

***(The Most Obvious of the Many) Limitations***

- Fails (false negative) if name of callee (a function to be invoked) is specified as a quoted identifier.
- Fails (false negative) if name of callee is passed as argument.
- Fails (false negative) if name of callee is read from a relation at runtime.
- Fails (false negative) if name of callee is assembled from tokens.
- Fails (false positive) if name of callee is present just as literal.
- Fails (false positive) if name of callee is present in a multi-line comment.
- Does not account for function overloading.
- Does not account for functions invoked via triggers.
- Does not account for functions invoked per query-rewrite rules.
- Does not account for effects of query rewriting rules.
- Knows nothing about functions written in non-interpreted PLs like C.

***Sample Output***

`Your routine...         |         ...calls these routines:` 
`---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------` 
 `create_silo_indexes             | {get_config__f_l__ea_silo,subst_silo_id}` 
 `demux__id_creat_thread          | {}` 
 `grow__sensor_thhourly           | {containing_hhour_t_begin}`

***SQL***

```
WITH routine_names AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT(Lower(proname)) AS name                              --#0
    FROM pg_proc
    WHERE proowner = To_Regrole(current_role)
)
SELECT
    name AS "Your routine...",
    Array_Remove(                                                        --#8
        Array(                                                           --#7
            SELECT Unnest(                                               --#5
                String_To_Array(                                         --#4
                    Regexp_Replace(                                      --#3
                        Regexp_Replace(                                  --#2
                            Lower(PG_Get_Functiondef(To_Regproc(name)))  --#1
                            , '--.*?\n', '', 'g'
                        )
                        , '\W+', ' ', 'g'
                    )
                    , ' '
                )
            )
            INTERSECT                                                    --#6
            SELECT name FROM routine_names
            ORDER BY 1
        )
        , name
    ) AS "...calls these routines:"
FROM
    routine_names;
```

***How It Works***

- **#0** Collect names of all the routines which could be callers and/or callees.  We cannot handle overloaded functions correctly anyway, so just `DISTINCT` to save trouble later on; SQL is case-insensitive apart from quoted identifiers which we are not bothering with anyway, so we just `Lower()` to simplify comparison later.
- **#1** `PG_Get_Functiondef()` fetches complete text of the `CREATE FUNCTION` or `CREATE PROCEDURE` command.  Again, `Lower()`.
- **#2** Strip single-line comments.  Note the lazy (non-greedy) `*?` quantifier: the usual `*` quantifier, if used here, would remove the first single-line comment *plus* all subsequent lines!
- **#3** Replace all characters other than letters and digits and `_`, with a space.  Note the `+` quantifier: it ensures that 2+ contiguous removed characters are replaced by just 1 space.
- **#4** Split by spaces into an array; this array contains bits of SQL syntax, literals, numbers, and identifiers including routine names.
- **#5** Unnest the array into a rowset.
- **#6** `INTERSECT` with routine names; result will consist of routine names only.
- **#7** Convert rowset into an array.
- **#8** Since input was complete text of a `CREATE FUNCTION f ...` command, extracted routine names will obviously contain `f` itself; so we remove it with `Array_Remove()`.

---

---

(SQL tested with PostgreSQL 12.1)